# React Native - useRef for an array (Expo)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Been using Expo and RN on an app, but I'm stuck with a problem. I'm using [Expo Video](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/)
to make a photo/video gallery. The problem is, if I have more than 1 video in the array, only the last one will play (problem with useRef). And I couldn't find a way to create a ref for each one of them.

***Solutions that I've tried and half worked: I created a `VideoComponent` (as a function then added on return), and each component had its own `useRef` and `useState` for playing inside the component a different `useRef/useState` for video/status for each. It worked okay-ish. But the problem was when other states changed (user presses like, for example). Whenever a state changes, and rerenders, the whole video reset to the beginning. Which is not ok.***
The video reset on state change of other components doesn't affect the video if doing it normally (one useRef/state) but as I said, It's only playing the last component, which is not okay.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

function App(props) {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([
    {
      medias: [
        { link: 'https://link.com/link1.avi', mediaExtension: 'avi' },
        { link: 'https://link.com/link2.jpg', mediaExtension: 'jpg' },
        { link: 'https://link.com/link3.mov', mediaExtension: 'mov' },
      ],
      name: 'Name',
      description: 'description',
    },
  ]);
  const video = useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState({});

  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={allData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{}}>
            {item.medias.map((item) => (
              <View>
                {item.mediaExtension === 'mov' || 'avi' || 'WebM' ? (
                  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() =>
                        video.isPlaying
                          ? video.current.pauseAsync()
                          : video.current.playAsync()
                      }>
                      <Video
                        ref={video}
                        style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
                        source={{
                          uri: item.link,
                        }}
                        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) =>
                          setStatus(() => status)
                        }
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <Image style={{}} source={{ uri: item.link }} />
                )}
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to create a FlatList of Videos, and `onScroll` you want to pause it. This can be implemented as shown below

Also, here is a [Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/flatlist-of-videos) for this

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import VideoPlayer from './components/VideoPlayer';

const Videos = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    source: require('./assets/videoplayback.mp4'),
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    source: require('./assets/videoplayback.mp4'),
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    source: require('./assets/videoplayback.mp4'),
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    source: require('./assets/videoplayback.mp4'),
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    source: require('./assets/videoplayback.mp4'),
  },
  {
    _id: 6,
    source: require('./assets/videoplayback.mp4'),
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [Viewable, SetViewable] = React.useState([]);
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  const onViewRef = React.useRef((viewableItems) => {
    let Check = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < viewableItems.viewableItems.length; i++) {
      Check.push(viewableItems.viewableItems[i].item);
    }
    SetViewable(Check);
  });

  const viewConfigRef = React.useRef({ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 80 });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={Videos}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <VideoPlayer {...item} viewable={Viewable} />}
        ref={ref}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        viewabilityConfig={viewConfigRef.current}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

and `VideoPLayer` component looks like this

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Video, AVPlaybackStatus } from 'expo-av';

export default function VideoPlayer({ viewable, _id, source }) {
  const video = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (viewable) {
      if (viewable.length) {
        if (viewable[0]._id === _id) {
          video.current.playAsync();
        } else {
          video.current.pauseAsync();
        }
      } else {
        video.current.pauseAsync();
      }
    } else {
      video.current.pauseAsync();
    }
  }, [viewable]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        source={source}
        rate={1.0}
        volume={1.0}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
        isLooping
        shouldPlay
        style={styles.video}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    marginBottom: 100,
    marginTop: 100,
  },
  video: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: 300,
  },
});
```

Comment: Your example works fine, but I couldn't find a way to implement it into my own FlatList ( as you can see, I have a flatList with images/videos as data, and inside them I check if extension is video or image). Your example doesn't quite let me do that

Comment: Also I don't want it to be scrolled. I only want a button that can pause/play